# How to pass props to React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that returns an object containing a component and I am passing props from my function to the component but I see the props coming as an empty object.

```
export function withBackgroundRed<TProps = any>(
  Component: any,
  props?: TProps
) {
  console.log('props', props);
  return {
    Wrapper: function Wrapper(p = props) {
      console.log('p', p);
      return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <Component {...p} />
        </div>
      );
    },
  };
}

function App(props) {
  return <div>props: {JSON.stringify(props)}</div>;
}

const WithSomeContext = withBackgroundRed(App, { props1: 'props1' }).Wrapper;

export default WithSomeContext;
```

The first. console.log() print the props as expected, but the second one is just an empty object.

[Here a live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fkmczf?description=React%20%20%20TypeScript%20starter%20project&file=src%2FApp.tsx&title=React%20Starter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because React will always pass an object with the live props to a component you render.

So the default value you use for `p` will never be used, as it will receive the props used (*an empty object if no props where passed when rendering the wrapped component*).

You should merge the initial props with the ones provided to to the wrapped component.

Something like

```js
export function withBackgroundRed<TProps = any>(
  Component: any,
  props?: TProps
) {
  console.log('props', props);
  return {
    Wrapper: function Wrapper(instanceProps) {
      const mergedProps: TProps = Object.assign({}, props, instanceProps);
      console.log('mergedProps', mergedProps);
      return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <Component {...mergedProps} />
        </div>
      );
    },
  };
}
```

*You can swap the `props, instanceProps` in the `Object.assign` depending on which ones you want to prevail in case of conflict.*

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rlxcy7

Comment: Thanks a lot, spent few hours trying to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more convenient way to do this kind of wrapper:

```js
interface IWrapperProps = {
  Children: React.Element,
  props?: any
}

const Wrapper = (props: IWrapperProps) => {

   return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </div>
   )

}

const WithSomeContext = (props) => <Wrapper props={props}><App/></Wrapper>

export default WithSomeContext
```